# Assembly help explanation of cltq

Tags: assembly

> ```
>     movl    -60(%rbp), %eax
>     cltq
>     salq    $3, %rax
>     movq    %rax, %rdi
>     .cfi_offset 3, -24
> ```

can any one explain what  the above block of code means / does

eg  what does          salq    $3, %rax do

thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
movl    -60(%rbp), %eax      ;load a 32 bit (int) parameter or local var from the stack
cltq                         ;sign extend to 64 bit
salq    $3, %rax             ;shift left by 3 (multiply with 8)
movq    %rax, %rdi           ;move the value (possibly an offset) to rdi
```

This looks like a part of an address calculation. Hard to say because a lot is missing.